# Sobolev inequality in negative index

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lebesgue-integral

For $s>n/2$, is it true that
$$ \int |fg| dx\leq ||f||_{H^s}||g||_{H^{-s}}?$$
This inequality is used on pg 398 of the Majda Bertozzi book on Vorticity and Incompressible flow but I can't make sense of it.
Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to provide more information here. The text segment in question is heavy on notation, and in general hard to read. You should mention e.g. that $f$ is assumed to lie in $H^s_0$ (since $H^{-s}$ is the dual space of $H^s_0$). What assumptions $g$ meets in the text in question I could not tell.

Comment: I believe that for $s = 1$, this follows from Theorem 1 in section 5.9.1 of Evans's Partial Differential Equations. See http://books.google.com/books?id=Xnu0o_EJrCQC&pg=PA299

Answer (score 2):

$H^{-s}$ is by definition the dual of $H^s$. I suppose that $\int f\,g\,dx$ must be understood in the sense of duality. Elements of $H^{-s}$ are not functions, but distributions, so that $f\,g$ is not defined in general. If for instance both $f$ and $g$ are in the Schwartz class, then
$$
\Bigl|\int f\,g\,dx\Bigr|=\Bigl|\int\hat f\,\hat g\,d\xi\Bigr|=\Bigl|\int\hat f\,\langle\xi\rangle^{s/2}\,\hat g\,\langle\xi\rangle^{-s/2}\,d\xi\Bigr|\le\|f\|_{H^s}\,\|g\|_{H^{-s}}.
$$

Comment: Thank you, I thought maybe this had a meaning only in the sense of the dual bracket $<.,.>_{H^{-s},H^{s}}$ but this inequality is used for $g$ a distribution. But then wouldn't this hold for all $s$, without the restriction $s>n/2$?

Comment: @anonymous So what is the dual of $H^1(\mathbb{R^n})$?